# Callback for style change of element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Sorry for my little knowledge about Javascript, but I really want to ask about this:
I have a following CSS rule:

```
.myClass {
    transition: .3s all;
 }
```

And following js in `<script>`:

```
[node].style.transform = "translateX(-100px)";
[node].className = "myClass";

// do stuffs for transition end event
```

I don't understand why the node moves towards left for 100px **WITH** the transition effect. Isn't that true that Javascript code executes line by line? It seems that setTimout([callback], 10) does solve the problem, but why exactly?

Comment: DOM related changes will not get to the UI as soon as the script is executed... the update view will be rendered only after the current script execution is completed.. so you will have both the translate and transition rule set by then

Comment: JS doesn't always execute code line by line. Some code may run asynchronously as is probably the case here.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why the node moves towards left for 100px WITH the transition effect. Isn't that true that Javascript code executes line by line?

The JavaScript executes line by line, but the browser monitors for changes to the DOM in a separate thread and updates things in bulk.

The [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event will fire when the transition has completed.

Comment: Interestingly run multiple times within a Stack Snippet I was unable to replicate the problem, but the problem is present if I run it in JSFiddle. Any idea why the two would behave differently? (It didn't happen at all within the Stack Snippet, but happens every time in JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/t1k7n6uo/)).